# ActionBar padding between elements:

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to put padding between items in the action bar - specially my logo and the Navigation drawer icon, following is the style I am using:

```
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo_header</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
        <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

However these two dont seem to work:

```
<item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
<item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: if your using jelly bean or up go on your device go to developer options and turn on 'show layout boundaries'. It might help you to see the margins better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make the logo into a drawable layer list instead and that way i can set its padding something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_main_icon"
        android:right="20dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

And if you use this please update your manifest to use this drawable as the main icon instead of the current.

update: it might be better to use this icon as a logo as per reading on stackOverFlow.
so in your manifest in application tag set android:logo="my_main_icon" , researching this still.

update:  if you use logo i think you have to turn it on in the actionbar...

> setDisplayUseLogoEnabled() Enables the use of an alternative image (a
>   "logo") in the Action Bar, instead of the default application icon. A
>   logo is often a wider, more detailed image that represents the
>   application

Answer (score 2):

i think the correct syntax here would be:

```
<item
...
android:layout_padding="12dp"
...
/>
```

Comment: No there is no list view associated, I am talking about the standard buttons and Icons in the Action Bar.

Comment: yup sorry i missunderstood something here .. but i just edited the answer :D

Comment: Cheers, there is not much difference :)

Comment: and did it not work like this? the syntax of "<item name="android:padding">12dp</item>" just seems so wrong.

Comment: Yes there is some problem there ended up making a padded image view to use!